# Resource Not Found Exception after updating target sdk to 26 from 22

Tags: android, xamarin.android, drawable

In my Xamarin.Android when I update my target sdk to 26 (previously 22) the app gets crashed when inflating the button where it is set as foregroundTint, here

```
 <Button
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_30sdp"
    android:id="@+id/btnSharing"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
    android:background="@drawable/round_button"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/_15sdp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:textSize="@dimen/_18sdp"
    android:textColor="@color/FontLightColor"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:splitMotionEvents="false"
    android:foregroundTint="@drawable/ic_more_vertoption"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
```

and the exception is

```
 08-02 18:57:40.665 Motorola XT1254 Info    18860   MonoDroid   Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-xxxhdpi-v4/ic_more_vertoption.png from drawable resource ID #0x7f020097: .xml extension required
at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateListForCookie(Resources.java:2761)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java:2702)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:485)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4304)
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:677)
at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:109)
at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:105)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:70)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:66)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:109)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1016)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1073)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:746)
```

althought the png file is present in drawable as well as drawable-xxxhdpi folder. And it is not throwing it when target is 22. 
I am new to android development, help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: put the file in **drawable** folder  only.

Answer (score 2):

[Foreground Tint](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#attr_android:foregroundTint) attribute will take color not a png drawable, use a color to set tint.

[android:foregroundTint](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#attr_android:foregroundTint)
Tint to apply to the foreground.

May be a color value, in the form of "#rgb", "#argb", "#rrggbb", or "#aarrggbb".